# Mock RedisTemplate in Spring Boot Camel

Tags: unit-testing, spring-boot, redis, apache-camel, mockito

I'm trying to mock `RedisTemplate` for a unit test. I know it's possible to mock Redis using Camel Test API, but I have lot of Redis requests and I find Mockito API much more simple and easier to use. 
Below is the test I wrote and which throws `JedisConnectionException`.

So why my mock doesn't work?

```
@RunWith(CamelSpringBootRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(CustomerRoute.class)
@DirtiesContext(classMode = DirtiesContext.ClassMode.AFTER_EACH_TEST_METHOD)
@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude = RedisAutoConfiguration.class)
public class CustomerRouteTest extends CamelTestSupport {

@Autowired
private CamelContext camelContext;

@Override
protected CamelContext createCamelContext() throws Exception {
    return camelContext;
}

@Test
public void routeIsProcessingTheFile() throws Exception {
   // ....
}

@Configuration
static class Config {

    @Bean
    RedisTemplate<?, ?> redisTemplate() {
        RedisTemplate<?, ?> template = mock(RedisTemplate.class);
        RedisConnectionFactory connectionFactory = mock(RedisConnectionFactory.class);
        RedisConnection connection = mock(RedisConnection.class);

        when(template.getConnectionFactory()).thenReturn(connectionFactory);
        when(connectionFactory.getConnection()).thenReturn(connection);

        when(template.opsForSet()).thenReturn(mock(SetOperations.class));
        when(template.opsForHash()).thenReturn(mock(HashOperations.class));

        return template;
    }
}
}
```

I'm using:

```
'org.apache.camel:camel-spring-boot-starter:2.20.1'
'org.apache.camel:camel-spring-redis:2.20.1'
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that I didn't include template in `toD` URI and camel was using some default template (I guess). So the fix is:

```
&redisTemplate=#customTemplate
```